# How do I return a part of text with a certain word in the middle?

Tags: php

If this is the input string:

> $input = 'In biology (botany), a "fruit" is a part of a flowering
>   plant that derives from specific tissues of the flower, mainly one or
>   more ovaries. Taken strictly, this definition excludes many structures
>   that are "fruits" in the common sense of the term, such as those
>   produced by non-flowering plants';

And now I want to perform a search on the word *tissues* and consequently return only a part of the string, defined by where the result is, like this:

> $output = '... of a flowering plant that derives from specific **tissues** of the flower, mainly one or more ovaries ...';

The search term may be in the middle.

How do I perform the aforementioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to my other answer using `preg_match`:

```
$word = 'tissues'

$matches = array();

$found = preg_match("/\b(.{0,30}$word.{0,30})\b/i", $string, $matches);

if ($found == 0) {
    // string not found
} else {

    $output = $matches[1];

}
```

This may be better as it uses word boundaries.

EDIT:  To surround the search term with a tag, you'll need to slightly alter the regex.  This should do it:

```
$word = 'tissues'

$matches = array();

$found = preg_match("/\b(.{0,30})$word(.{0,30})\b/i", $string, $matches);

if ($found == 0) {
    // string not found
} else {

    $output = $matches[1] . "<strong>$word</strong>" . $matches[2];

}
```

Comment: Haha, why not combine the answers :P

Comment: I thought it would be interesting to see which one people like the best :-)

Comment: great, this works, accepting! thanks. one more optional question though - how would I return the text so that the search string is bolded? that means put it inside <strong> in the output

Comment: i was about to construct some very complicated solution using arrays, but your solution shows again the power of regular expressions. very nice and simple solution!

Comment: Thanks.  My first thought was use `explode`, but regular expressions are so much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

User `strpos` to find the location of the word and `substr` to extract the quote.  For example:

```
$word = 'tissues'

$pos = strpos($string, $word);

if ($pos === FALSE) {
    // string not found
} else {

    $start = $pos - 30;
    if ($start < 0)
        $start = 0;


    $output = substr($string, $start, 70);

}
```

Use `stripos` for case insensitive search.